# Redis Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charCodeAt')

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, redis, node-redis

I'm using the `npm` package `node-redis` version `3.1.0` and I've included the following in my `.vue` file, specifically in the `<script></script>` block:

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';
```

Inside `methods` for `export default`, I have the following:

```
async getVal(redisKey) {
  const client = createClient();
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  client.on('error', (err) => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
  await client.connect();
  const value = await client.get(redisKey);
  return value;
},
```

The code compiles with no errors, but when I launch my site in the browser, I get the following error in my browser console:

```
index.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'charCodeAt')
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:3)
    at Object.f3c2 (chunk-vendors.bcef36a0.js:73)
    at i (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.b620 (customErrors.js:5)
    at i (bootstrap:79)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:9)
    at Object.a111 (chunk-vendors.bcef36a0.js:41)
    at i (bootstrap:79)
    at Module.56d7 (app.05cc1827.js:1)
    at i (bootstrap:79)
(anonymous) @   index.js:3
f3c2        @   chunk-vendors.bcef36a0.js:73
i           @   bootstrap:79
b620        @   customErrors.js:5
i           @   bootstrap:79
(anonymous) @   index.js:9
a111        @   chunk-vendors.bcef36a0.js:41
i           @   bootstrap:79
56d7        @   app.05cc1827.js:1
i           @   bootstrap:79
0           @   app.05cc1827.js:1
i           @   bootstrap:79
a           @   bootstrap:45
(anonymous) @   bootstrap:152
(anonymous) @   app.05cc1827.js:1
```

`index.js`:

```
'use strict'

const Errors = process.version.charCodeAt(1) < 55 && process.version.charCodeAt(2) === 46
  ? require('./lib/old') // Node.js < 7
  : require('./lib/modern')

module.exports = Errors
```

How do I fix this? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong that would cause this error.

Comment: Thats mean `process.version` is `undefined`. Make sure you didn't override/clear version value somewhere in your code

Comment: @Xeelley Would `package.json` or `package-lock.json` affect that?

Comment: Not real, sadly. Also check out, maybe you declared `process` variable somewhere and override whole process object by accident.

Comment: node-redis is Node lib (as the name suggests), and you're trying to use it in browser app.